# Connect By no SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, query

Tenho uma *query* que funciona no Oracle mas não está funcionando no SQL Server.

A tabela que tenho gravada tem uma data inicial e data final na mesma linha, mas quando passa de um dia para o outro precisava olhar quanto tempo teve em um dia

```
Dt_Ini     | Dt_fim
30/03/2017 | 31/03/2017
```

Precisava que listasse

```
Dt_ini 30/03/2017  //e na outra linha
Dt ini 31/03/2017
```

```
SELECT DATABASEEXT, CODCRE, USU_TIPIND, CODMTV, USU_PARPRO, SUM(QTDHRS) AS QTDHRS 
FROM(   
    WITH tabela as (
    SELECT usu_dtinpa AS DT_INI,
           usu_dtfipa AS DT_FIM,
           usu_hrinpa AS HRBFIM,
        usu_tctrpar.*
        FROM usu_tctrpar
        WHERE usu_dtinpa  BETWEEN '01/03/2017' AND '31/03/2017'
        AND usu_seqapt = 181
        ),
    results as (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            usu_CODCRE, usu_CODMTV, 
             CASE WHEN (DT_INI + LEVEL - 1) <> (DT_INI) THEN
                       (DT_INI + LEVEL - 1)
               ELSE DT_INI
             END DATABASEEXT,

             CASE WHEN (DT_INI + LEVEL - 1) <> (DT_FIM) THEN
                       (DT_INI + LEVEL) 
               ELSE DT_FIM
             END DATA_FIM,      
            HORINI, HORFIM,
             CASE WHEN (DT_INI + LEVEL - 1) <> (DT_FIM) THEN HORINI

                  WHEN HORFIM <= 1407 AND CODCRE = '901' THEN HORINI 
                  WHEN HORFIM >  1407 AND CODCRE = '902' THEN 1440 

                  WHEN HORFIM <= 1320 AND CODCRE = '901' THEN HORINI  
                  WHEN HORFIM >  1320 AND CODCRE = '902' THEN 1440    

               ELSE 1320
             END HORINI2,

             CASE WHEN (DT_INI + LEVEL - 1) <> (DT_FIM) AND CODCRE ='902' THEN 1407
                  WHEN HORFIM > 1407 AND CODCRE ='901'  THEN HORFIM

                  WHEN (DT_INI + LEVEL - 1) <> (DT_FIM) AND CODCRE ='901' THEN 1320
                  WHEN HORFIM > 1320 AND CODCRE ='902'  THEN HORFIM

             ELSE HORFIM
            END HORFIM2
          FROM tabela
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <=  (DT_FIM - DT_INI) + 1
        )
    SELECT results.*, results.HORFIM2 -  results.HORINI2 AS QTDHRS, E018MTV.USU_TIPIND, E018MTV.USU_PARPRO
      FROM results, E018MTV
      WHERE DATABASEEXT BETWEEN '01/03/2017' AND '31/03/2017'
      AND results.codmtv = E018MTV.CODMTV
    ORDER BY  DATABASEEXT, HORINI
    )
GROUP BY DATABASEEXT, CODCRE, USU_TIPIND, CODMTV, USU_PARPRO
ORDER BY DATABASEEXT, CODCRE, CODMTV
```

Comment: Se puder criar uma tabela de apoio, veja esta resposta http://stackoverflow.com/a/959821/6378641

Comment: @RodrigoLeão: O que ocorre quando executa no SQL Server a consulta acima? // Como estão declaradas as colunas usu_dtinpa e usu_dtfipa?